# awk shebang doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a simple `awk` program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {print "work already!"}
```

If I run it as:

```
awk -f panic
```

on the (osx) terminal it works.  But it fails if I try running it as a script:

```
. panic
-bash: BEGIN: command not found
```

I checked the location of awk using `which awk` and it is indeed located at `/usr/bin/awk`. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a file as a script you must type:

```
./<script>
```

**Edit**:

As pointed by William Pursell, `.` is not an alias for `source`, but the exact contrary.

> . is not an alias for source. . is the sh standard command for running another script inside the current shell. source is a command that originated in csh and was adopted by many sh clones as an alias for .. If source is to be viewed as anything but an abomination, it is an alias for ., not the other way around.

Comment: `.` is *not* an alias for `source`.  `.` is the `sh` standard command for running another script inside the current shell.  `source` is a command that originated in `csh` and was adopted by many `sh` clones as an alias for `.`.  If `source` is to be viewed as anything but an abomination, it is an alias for `.`, not the other way around.

Comment: <weep>My answer was first...</weep>

Comment: @WilliamPursell Out of interest, what's wrong with the source command? Is there a better way of achieving the same result? Or are you just saying it's an unnecessary duplication of . ?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with the source command per-se, just that it is an alias for `.` and it strikes me as incorrect to state that `.` is an alias for `source`.  However, strictly speaking, according to the open group standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) "If the command name matches the name of a utility listed in the following table, the results are unspecified." and `source` is one of the commands listed.  That is, it is non-standard and using it techinically results in unspecified behavior.  But in practice it will work in nearly all shells you are likely to use.

Answer (score 5):

Run it as `./panic`, not `. panic` , as the latter is the same as running `source panic`, which won't do what you want. See `man source`

Comment: should that not be `help source`?